# Cannot set Content More than once xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin and xaml to define my views.  I am getting an error that I dont understand.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:telerikDataControls="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls"
xmlns:telerikListView="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls.ListView;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls"
              xmlns:telerikPrimitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives"
xmlns:telerikInput="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Input;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Input" 
              xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WMS.ViewModels"

             x:Class="Views.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <ScrollView>
            <Frame x:Name="reprint" Padding="40" IsClippedToBounds="False"   CornerRadius="4">
                <telerikPrimitives:RadBorder BorderThickness="8" CornerRadius="10">

                    <StackLayout>

                        <Label Text=" Label"></Label>
                        <Label Text="Allows the User to reprint a label."></Label>

                        <telerikInput:RadButton BackgroundColor="#343C41" TextColor="White" Text="Label Reprint" x:Name="btnLabelReprint" Clicked="BtnLabelReprint_Clicked">

                        </telerikInput:RadButton>
                    </StackLayout>

                </telerikPrimitives:RadBorder>




            </Frame>
            <Frame x:Name="warehouseTransferr" Padding="40"    CornerRadius="4">
                <telerikPrimitives:RadBorder BorderThickness="8" CornerRadius="10">

                    <StackLayout>

                        <Label Text="Ware House Transfer"></Label>
                        <Label Text="Allows users to transfer from warehouse to waehouse"></Label>

                    <telerikInput:RadButton BackgroundColor="#343C41" TextColor="White" Text="Warehouse Transfer" x:Name="btnWarehouseTransfe" Clicked="BtnWarehouseTransfe_Clicked">

                            </telerikInput:RadButton>
                    </StackLayout>

                </telerikPrimitives:RadBorder>




            </Frame>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   XLS0501 The property 'Content' is set more than once.       HomePage.xaml   36

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have multiple children for a ScrollView, hence the error defining content more than once.

So, to fix this, you can encapsulate your content within a StackLayout:

```
  <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
            <Frame x:Name="reprint" Padding="40" IsClippedToBounds="False"   CornerRadius="4">
                <telerikPrimitives:RadBorder BorderThickness="8" CornerRadius="10">

                    <StackLayout>

                        <Label Text=" Label"></Label>
                        <Label Text="Allows the User to reprint a label."></Label>

                        <telerikInput:RadButton BackgroundColor="#343C41" TextColor="White" Text="Label Reprint" x:Name="btnLabelReprint" Clicked="BtnLabelReprint_Clicked">

                        </telerikInput:RadButton>
                    </StackLayout>

                </telerikPrimitives:RadBorder>
            </Frame>
            <Frame x:Name="warehouseTransferr" Padding="40"    CornerRadius="4">
                <telerikPrimitives:RadBorder BorderThickness="8" CornerRadius="10">

                    <StackLayout>

                        <Label Text="Ware House Transfer"></Label>
                        <Label Text="Allows users to transfer from warehouse to waehouse"></Label>

                    <telerikInput:RadButton BackgroundColor="#343C41" TextColor="White" Text="Warehouse Transfer" x:Name="btnWarehouseTransfe" Clicked="BtnWarehouseTransfe_Clicked">

                            </telerikInput:RadButton>
                    </StackLayout>

                </telerikPrimitives:RadBorder>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Just needed a second pair of eyes thought I may have been missing a stack thank you forms have come a long way since old day but some the error message less than helpfull.

Comment: Indeed this message is a little bit generic. But glad I could help :)